# Users, groups and others in a single user desktop installation

Tags: permissions

I understand how permissions can be granted and revoked, owners changed and so on.

I'd like to know if the groups' or others' attributes matter at all when I am the single user of a desktop edition (Ubuntu).

Couldn't the permissions by default be just -rw------- and -rwx------, that is 600 and 700? What's the point of granting r,w, or x to group or others, when you are not running a server?

Comment: The point is there might be services running as unprivileged UIDs that might need access to your files.  Try changing permissions for your `$HOME` to 0700, and see if you can ssh to your account.  Or the other way around, you might need to access a service that runs with special privileges.  Think printing or audio.

Comment: @SatōKatsura SSH will work just fine with a permission `700` home directory.  Other services might not though.

Answer (score 1):

User accounts serve two purposes.  I'm going to refer to "system accounts" and "user accounts".  On Ubuntu system accounts all have UID less than 1000.  Likewise system groups have GID less than 1000.

There are some single user systems which have done away with "user" accounts almost entirely such as Android (though in recent years, we've seen multi-user phones), and these often re-use the permissions model purely to separate system accounts.  This prevents programs from interfering with one another.

Now your laptop is setup to assume there will be multiple users, even if by default it only has one.  But despite the fact it only has one "user" it still has multiple system accounts.  And these are used to secure your system...

For security this is a good thing.  You don't want to accidentally run some malicious code and find it's taken over your entire system.  It's much better for the permissions model to stop "you" doing something you shouldn't.  Likewise some services (such as sound and printing) shouldn't be available to system programs which have no reason to access such things.

This means you should expect to have groups for allocating specific privileges such as `sudo` `audio` `cdrom`.  Even though your one user will be in all of these, it allows you to assign these groups to specific system users only when absolutely necessary.

So on a single user laptop you would expect to still have many system accounts and system groups, even though you have only one user account and user group.

---

For your own files (those in your home directory).  Generally you can set permission 700 on your home directory, banning access to everything but you and `root`, without much trouble.  There are occasional examples where you might want to set a different group and permissions, but these are usually an exception.  For example on one of my PCs I have a `music` group which provides access for [Plex Media Server](https://www.plex.tv/) to read my music.

Similarly you might want to set up some sort of [samba](https://www.samba.org/) share and it's possible this might force you to set a group permission to allow unauthenticated users to access *some* of your files.

But on the whole you can get away with banning everything from your home directory except your own user.